# In SharePoint Document Library, Identify document version where content has been modified

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, development, document-library, versioning

In a document library, I've some documents with version history.

How can we identify the versions where content(not metadata) of the file has been changed using C#?
I have tried by comparing the size. but in some scenarios size is same with new changes.

So can anybody help me to find the versions where content is modified?

Answer (score 0):

I'd develop an event receiver, that would trigger each time an update occurs. The code of the ER would compute the hash of the binary file (this assumes the file are not expected to be "too big") and store the result in a dedicated custom field.
When you go through the versions of the item, you can then compare the hash for each of them.